# how to bold active links in ui-router

Tags: css, angular, hyperlink, angular-ui-router

I have a multi step form that is using UI-router. I'm wondering how i can bold the active links and keep it bolded. right now the links only get bolded when i click on them and go back to its original css when i click out of it.

html:

```
          <div class="text-center">
              <a ui-sref-active="active" ui-sref=".info"><span>1</span> Personal Info</a>
              <a ui-sref-active="active" ui-sref=".events"><span>2</span> Interests</a>
              <a ui-sref-active="active" ui-sref=".submit"><span>3</span> Kewl Dawg</a>
          </div>
```

css:

```
a:active { 
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

here is a link to the plunkr:
https://embed.plnkr.co/PSpH6qdlm9JltgU2DAbj/

Solved:

just removed a: from the css....

Comment: you want 'a.active' the ":active" selector is for when the link is being clicked. ui router is adding a class '.active'

Comment: sweet thanks got it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ui-sref-active` adds a class, your css targets the ':active' pseudoclass.  use `a.active` in your css.

https://plnkr.co/edit/FcHpaV5ITXYqXLs0FwZL?p=preview